# Installing Dropbox folder on Linux/Ubuntu VM for Use With IPython Notebook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dropbox, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to following instructions on http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment as a basis for installing Dropbox onto a headless Ubuntu VM that I'm accessing via an IPython notebook in a browser on host machine.

```
!cd
!wget -O dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86_64"
```

gets the file okay, with the home directory set via vagrant to be /vagrant/notebooks, a directory shared between the VM and host (the idea is the shared directory will be available to the user on host and the VM IPython notebook user).

`tar tzf` looks reasonable in its output,

```
!tar -tzf dropbox.tar.gz
```

but `!tar -xzf dropbox.tar.gz` fails:

```
!tar -xzf dropbox.tar.gz
tar: .dropbox-dist/dropbox: Cannot hard link to `.dropbox-dist/library.zip': Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

This seems to be reported elsewhere but I can't see a fix? Is the problem to do with the location I'm trying to install the Dropbox folder into perhaps? (In the general case there may well be another Dropbox folder elsewhere on the host machine.)

Comment: I'm assuming you can't just ssh to the vm and install dropbox that way, and then use iPython notebook to connect to the machine later? Also, why put dropbox there? if it's just to provide an easy symlinked directory to your host, could you consider using another method? The Virtualbox synced directories is working very well for me. I am running several vms managed by vagrant www.vagrantup.com with iPython notebook running on them and synced directories that allow me to run code via iPython on the vm but access files that are on my host machine without any further rcp/scp actions or the like.

Comment: One possible use of the VM is that it should be deployable by students on a remote host as well as their own machine. Some mechanism would be required to synch data and programme files between the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vm managed through vagrant and got dropbox running on it via iPython notebook without using ssh at all. Here's what I did. Note - there are still some issues to be worked out, but I did get it to install okay.

The key step you're missing is that `!cd` doesn't actually take you to your user home directory (AFAICT it doesn't do anything at all), and then a piece of the dropbox installation fails, as you've seen.

Also note: my username is "vagrant" on this machine and I am connecting to it through iPython Notebook in my host web browser via port-forwarding.

**How I installed Dropbox via iPython Notebook**

```
import os
!cd "/home/vagrant"
os.chdir('/home/vagrant/')
!wget -O dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86"
!tar -xzf dropbox.tar.gz
!./.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

**Connect your headless machine to your dropbox account**
After this, follow the instructions from that dropbox how-to you linked above and do the following:

1. Log in or create an account on https://dropbox.com in some web browser
2. Once logged in, paste the url that you'll find in the output of your last iPython notebook command.
3. Click whatever OK buttons to link the account to the headless machine.

**Symlinking notebook to Dropbox for convenience**
Now make Dropbox more accessible to iPython notebook:

`!ln -s '/home/vagrant/Dropbox' '/vagrant/notebook/Dropbox'`

**Running dropbox**
The only issue remaining is getting dropbox to start as a service. I've been playing around with the upstart method in your linked how-to doc, but I ran out of time tonight to get it working. (I'm needing to write to /etc without the proper permissions via iPython notebook). I'll update this if I get more time this weekend to make it work.